# Rails Load Dropdowns from another model based on values in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model for checklist questions

Models List

OrderChecklist --> Saving the ChecklistQuestions Responses.

OrderChecklistQuest -->CheckList Questions.

ChecklistDpValues --> CheckList Question DropDown Values

Load all the questions from OrderCheckListQuest Model, OrderCheckListQuest has some questions have dropdowns so I created another Model named as OrderDpValues.
and my question is how to show the dpvalues to views?

My View is :

```
<%= simple_form_for @order_checklist, :url => add_path do |f| %>
<% @chk_quest.each do |chk| %>
<div class="clear row-space marginleft5">
<div class="clearfix">
  <div>
    <div class="checklist_label pull-left" <% if chk.dp_id == 'Y' %>  style="width: 281px;" else style="" <% end %>>
      <%= chk.questions  %>
    </div>
    <% if chk.dp_id == 'Y' %>
    <div class="pull-left">

    </div>
    <% end  %>
    <div class="checklist_option pull-left">
      <%= text_field "", "order_checklist[chk_sale][#{ chk.id }]" ,:class=>'checklist_input validate[required]'  %>
    </div>
    <div class="checklist_option pull-left">
      <%= text_field "", "order_checklist[chk_SE][#{ chk.id }]" ,:class=>'checklist_input validate[required]'  %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></div><% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not clear, what you want to do?

Comment: @Sontya i have some questions with dropdown values how to do with it

Comment: see the image link i had posted in question i had mentioned drop-down with brown color.

Comment: rather than creating seperate table for choices questions, in the same table only specify the `question_type` like text, multiple_choice, single_choice and based on `question_type` show dropdown, or plain text question

Comment: @Sontya I had updated my question pls help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering in that orderchecklistquests table and questions is another table which has questions, so loop thorough questions so I get each question.
Question object has content has which can be a array e.g ["Yes", "No", "None"]

`<%= chk.questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= select_tag "content", options_for_select(question.content) %>`

Comment: Actually i had included "dp_id" one column in CheckListQuestion Table U see my view it shows the <% if chk.dp_id == 'Y' %> this condition for dropdown exits or not ..

Comment: My problem is how to load dropdowns runtime dynamically based on values

Comment: why do you mean by dynamically, those values are in database, correct, you just have pull for each question right?

Comment: where you have stored this dropdown options, which you want to show iin dropdown. and how you have saved those as array or what

Comment: I Stored in Seprate table(CheckDpValues) with foreignkey

Comment: can you please show, some code from model and what is your data?

Comment: My CheckListQuest Table 
#<OrderChecklistQuest id: 23, created_at: "2015-02-18 06:27:04", updated_at: "2015-02-19 07:42:31", questions: "3 Is Broadband Access part of this order?", dp_id: "Y", question_value: nil>
My DropDown Table
#<ChecklistDpValues id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-19 06:33:12", updated_at: "2015-02-19 06:33:12", dp_values: "Yes, Single Loc", chk_ques_id: "23">,

Comment: make dp_values an array like `["Yes", "Single Loc"]`

Comment: See my updated Question...Actually one set dropdown as Yes,Single Loc
And another set has Yes,No another set as Yes, Dont Know wat to do???

Comment: so define dp_values as array first of all, yes whatever the values accordingly save in `ChecklistDpValues` dp_vallues

Comment: i cant understand  ChecklistDpValues is a master table.

Comment: In your model `ChecklistDpValues` add line `serialize :dp_values, Array` this will make dp_values an array, then push values yes, no,etc.